# bx dev build --debug successfully completes, but can't run bx dev run

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I can successfully run `bx dev build` and successfully run my container locally with `bx dev run`.

When I execute `bx dev build --debug --trace`, I get successful completion, and my unit test passed. However, immediately after when I execute `bx dev run` I get:

> FAILED
>   A successful build of the project is required before running bx dev run. Verify that bx dev build completes successfully before attempting bx dev run

There seems to be something in the debug build that is holding me up, but it finishes successful. Any thoughts?  The tail end of my debug trace below (full trace blows the char limit):

```
Results :


Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ gapstrainingbff ---
[INFO] Building jar: /project/target/gapstrainingbff-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 

[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ gapstrainingbff ---

[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ gapstrainingbff ---

[INFO] Installing /project/target/gapstrainingbff-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /project/.m2/repository/projects/gapstrainingbff/1.0-SNAPSHOT/gapstrainingbff-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /project/pom.xml to /project/.m2/repository/projects/gapstrainingbff/1.0-SNAPSHOT/gapstrainingbff-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 54.659 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-22T21:39:29+00:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/31M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

OK
Process time: 57.911463s
Stopping the 'bx-dev-gapstrainingbff-tools' container...
OK
acmartinez@Andreas-MacBook-Air gaps-training-bff $ idt run
FAILED
A successful build of the project is required before running bx dev run. Verify that bx dev build completes successfully before attempting bx dev run

acmartinez@Andreas-MacBook-Air gaps-training-bff $
```

Comment: Could you try running with the `--trace` flag? I will notify the `idt` team about this issue.

Comment: @joe "full trace blows the char limit"

Answer (score 3):

When you run `bx dev build --debug`, the IDT CLI builds the application for debugging so that you can execute `bx dev debug`. In order to build your application for `release` and execute `bx dev run`, you must first execute `bx dev build` without the `--debug` flag. The order of commands matters in this case.
See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cloudnative/idt/commands.html#run